# C++ Adding new pointer objects to List

Tags: c++, list, pointers, object, addition

I have a data structure defined up here called this:

```
   typedef list <classSpec*> ClassSpecList;
```

I'm trying to add stuff into the list here based on functions that return certain values of that match the same data type.  In one function, I have a list pointer object defined here and I have another statement that calls a function.

```
 ClassSpecList *answer = 0;

 classSpec *thisanswer = parseClass(br);
```

Basically I'm trying to add the results of what `thisanswer` returns into my main `ClassSpecList`.  Problem is, when I try

```
answer->push_back(new classSpec (*thisanswer));
```

It compiles but I get a seg fault

When I try somethign else like:

```
answer->insert(ClassSpecList.begin(), *thisanswer);
```

I keep getting primary expression errors and I do not know why.  I even tried it with other list made without `typedef` and I still get those.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you seem to like using pointers and dynamic allocation, it could be that `classSpec` manages resources but does not follow [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). Alternatively, it could be the fact that `answer` is not initialized.

Comment: `ClassSpecList.begin()` should be `answer->begin()`. You are allocating `answer` somewhere right?

Comment: You use c++11? Note that elsewhere `push_back(new classSpec (*thisanswer));` gives a memory leak.

What are the data in *thisanswer? check that pointer points to the correct object.

Comment: Please avoid pointers

Comment: And is *answer allocated in memory? What if put it on the stack;
`ClassSpecList answer;
answer.push_back();`

Comment: Thats what I'm unsure about.  I do not know how to point answer to thisanswer correctly or add the results to the list.  I'm quite new to allocating pointers and I can't even explain it well.  I have a function that thisanswer that is initialized to that does stuff and returns a new object of type classSpec `return new classSpec(c);` for instance.  Basically I'm trying to add those results to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the pointer `answer` first, like :

```
ClassSpecList *answer = new ClassSpecList;
```

then you can add `thisAnswer` into this list.

Comment: My list didn't Hang during run-time.  I just need to iterate it.  This also leads to my side issue with the primary-expression.  I make a iterator for my list like so `ClassSpecList::iterator it;` but when i try to iterate it, i get a compile error: 
`Primary-expression before '.' token`  I've been getting this error even when I set up list that I knew that worked.

Comment: Fixed everything and even got my iterator to work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ClassSpecList *answer = new ClassSpecList;
answer->push_back(thisAnswer);
```

as should this, which is usually recommended:

```
ClassSpecList answer;
answer.push_back(thisAnswer);
```

If possible, `parseClass` shouldn't return a pointer, and you should use `typedef list <classSpec> ClassSpecList;`.